# Get background-color of element in DOM when clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, vuejs2

I have a mapping, with different colorful nodes linked together (or not) in d3.js.
When a user clicks somewhere, it's either on nodes, on the links between the nodes or on the black background.
What I would like is a way to get the color of the element I'm clicking, especially to know if it's outside the mapping, so a way to get "black" as a result (since the background is black).

```
const elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
const cssObj = window.getComputedStyle(elems, null);
let bgColor = cssObj.getPropertyValue("background-color");
console.log("The color clicked is : "+bgColor);
```

So far, this is the only code I've tested and I'm getting this error.[image]

I don't understand how this can come out. Help on this would really be appreciated I can't find anything. Also, here's what my mapping looks like.

[image]

Comment: "_`elems` is an element_". Nope, it's HTMLCollection.

Comment: Since you tagged this with D3, why not using a d3 getter? It's `selection.style("background-color")`.